# Binding MYSQL offset in php (string + $_POST value)

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way i can do something like this:

```
$offset = "OFFSET $_POST['offset']";

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 ? ");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $offset);
$stmt->execute();
```

If i put the variable directly in the query it works, but i need to bind it since users have access to that `$_POST` value, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The `OFFSET` would need to be in the query as well. Bind the `$offset` as an integer. `$stmt->bindParam(1,  $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);` and `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?` I think would do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OFFSET` need to be in query not in variable

```
$offset = $_POST['offset'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hmmm wonder who this @ssdffvsdf fella is, but he definitely has copy/paste down pat